# How to set up a general domain in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is my htaccess file and I want to replace "yourdomain.com" with something general. I tried `%{SERVER_NAME}` but it doesnt work as expected.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

I want allow only requests when HTTP_REFERER will match with SERVER_NAME or HTTP_HOST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

> In the below example, -strmatch is used to compare the REFERER against
>   the site hostname, to block unwanted hotlinking.
>
> ```
> RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}/*'"
> RewriteRule "^/images" "-" [F]
> ```

Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond